# Jquery, how set array key?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

How set keys in array jquery ?

```
var formData = [
   $('input[name=name]').val(),
   $('input[name=surname]').val(),
   $('input[name=year_of_birth]').val(),
   $('input[name=city_of_birth]').val(),
   $('input[name=university]').val(),
   $('input[name=insurance_number]').val()  
 ];
```

when i am try

```
   var formData = ['key' => value], than i get unexpected string
```

Comment: Arrays can only have numeric keys in javascript. Objects can have strings as keys.

Comment: @Charlotte Dunois no, i need something to send array with keys, because i am using ajax to get data and send to model

Comment: That's not possible. Arrays **cannot** have strings as keys. It's a limitation in Javascript. If you need string keys, objects are the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by Charlotte Dunois in JavaScript there are arrays and objects (PHP allows for associative arrays but they do not exist in JavaScript), the example you have there would be accessible by formdata[0-5] if you wanted to use a key you would need to use an object:

```
var formdata = {
    name: $('input[name=name]').val(),
    surname: $('input[name=surname]').val(),
    yob: $('input[name=year_of_birth]').val(),
    cob: $('input[name=city_of_birth]').val(),
    university: $('input[name=university]').val(),
    insuranceNumber: $('input[name=insurance_number]').val() 
}
```

If you are using JSON (which if you are not I would suggest going that route) once you send the ajax request and have it on the PHP side you can use json_decode to convert it to an object or associative array based on preference:

```
$arr = json_decode($_REQUEST['requestData'], true) //associative array $arr['formdata']['key']
$obj = json_decode($_REQUEST['requestData']) //object $arr->formdata->key
```

Even PHP will convert associative arrays to objects when you use json_encode. This is because associative arrays not always a thing outside of PHP where objects are.